# Vertical bootstrap panel header

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, panel

I am trying to design the vertical bootstrap header panel, and I have almost achieved it using this

```css
.panel
{
    position: relative;
}

.panel-default > .panel-leftheading
{
    color: #333;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border-color: #ddd;
}

.panel-primary > .panel-leftheading
{
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #428bca;
    border-color: #428bca;
}

.panel-success > .panel-leftheading
{
    color: #3c763d;
    background-color: #dff0d8;
    border-color: #d6e9c6;
}

.panel-info > .panel-leftheading
{
    color: #31708f;
    background-color: #d9edf7;
    border-color: #bce8f1;
}

.panel-warning > .panel-leftheading
{
    color: #8a6d3b;
    background-color: #fcf8e3;
    border-color: #faebcc;
}

.panel-danger > .panel-leftheading
{
    color: #a94442;
    background-color: #f2dede;
    border-color: #ebccd1;
}

.panel-leftheading
{
    width: 42px;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    border-right: 1px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
    border-top-right-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}

.panel-lefttitle
{
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: 15px;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: inherit;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: left top;
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform-origin: left top;
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform-origin: left top;
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform-origin: left top;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform-origin: left top;
    position: absolute;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.panel-rightbody
{
    float: left;
    margin-left: 45px;
    padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="page-header">
    </div>
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-6">

<div class="panel panel-primary">
  <div class="panel-leftheading">
      <h3 class="panel-lefttitle">Panel title</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-rightbody">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      
  </div>
    <div class="clearfix">
    </div>
</div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Now the header is set to the vertical but the font alignment is not as expected. the font on the header should be readable and must be horizontal like this image

[image: vertical Panel Bootstrap]

what css I need to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the `transform`s and the `margin-left` and add a `width` (set as 0 here) smaller than the `font-size`(16px here) to the get the effect:

```
.panel-lefttitle {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: inherit;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  text-align: center;
  width: 0;
}
```

Also note have added in `word-wrap: break-word` and `white-space: pre-wrap` for the text to flow vertically preserving whitespaces / line-breaks.

```css
.panel {
  position: relative;
}
.panel-default > .panel-leftheading {
  color: #333;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border-color: #ddd;
}
.panel-primary > .panel-leftheading {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #428bca;
  border-color: #428bca;
}
.panel-success > .panel-leftheading {
  color: #3c763d;
  background-color: #dff0d8;
  border-color: #d6e9c6;
}
.panel-info > .panel-leftheading {
  color: #31708f;
  background-color: #d9edf7;
  border-color: #bce8f1;
}
.panel-warning > .panel-leftheading {
  color: #8a6d3b;
  background-color: #fcf8e3;
  border-color: #faebcc;
}
.panel-danger > .panel-leftheading {
  color: #a94442;
  background-color: #f2dede;
  border-color: #ebccd1;
}
.panel-leftheading {
  width: 42px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border-right: 1px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
.panel-lefttitle {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: inherit;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  text-align: center;
  width: 0;
}
.panel-rightbody {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 45px;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="page-header">
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">

      <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-leftheading">
          <h3 class="panel-lefttitle">Panel title</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-rightbody">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
            irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
            irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

        </div>
        <div class="clearfix">
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

Let me know your feedback on this. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks It works but I can not see a proper space between panel and title. any ways to achieve?

Comment: set `width` as 0 and `whitespace: pre-wrap` and i think you have what you need?

Comment: @iGyan.Org edited the answer accordingly. pls check if it works for you?

Comment: You made my day! :)

Comment: cool... thanks for marking the answer as correct! And hope you upvote too! :)

Answer (score 1):

1. You could use manual styling through `<br>` elements but this would be annoying.
2. You could wrap every letter into its own `<span>` element. This would be more comfortable, but still way too static.
3. Use css. To be more precise, use `word-wrap`. To do so, you've to adjust your `.panel-lefttitle` styling like so:

   ```
   .panel-lefttitle {
       width: 0;
       word-break: break-word;
       margin-top: 0;
       margin-bottom: 0;
       font-size: 16px;
       color: inherit;
       position: absolute;
   }
   ```

You've to set `width:0` so every letter gets displayed in a separate line. [Live Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/j3brydp7/)

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful. I converted each letter into a span-element and rotated each one. It is not quite beautiful, but demonstrates how this could be solved.

I only added some JavaScript to achieve your desired behavior.

This code comes (partly) from Matt Whipple's answer [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12631174/2417204).

```js
$(function() {
    $(".panel-lefttitle").html(("<span>" + $(".panel-lefttitle").html().split("").join("</span><span>") + "</span>"));
    $(".panel-lefttitle span").each(function() {
        $(this).css({
            "-webkit-transform": "rotate(-90deg)",
            "display": "inline-block",
            "letter-spacing": "1em"
        });
    });
});
```

```css
.panel
{
    position: relative;
}

.panel-default > .panel-leftheading
{
    color: #333;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border-color: #ddd;
}

.panel-primary > .panel-leftheading
{
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #428bca;
    border-color: #428bca;
}

.panel-success > .panel-leftheading
{
    color: #3c763d;
    background-color: #dff0d8;
    border-color: #d6e9c6;
}

.panel-info > .panel-leftheading
{
    color: #31708f;
    background-color: #d9edf7;
    border-color: #bce8f1;
}

.panel-warning > .panel-leftheading
{
    color: #8a6d3b;
    background-color: #fcf8e3;
    border-color: #faebcc;
}

.panel-danger > .panel-leftheading
{
    color: #a94442;
    background-color: #f2dede;
    border-color: #ebccd1;
}

.panel-leftheading
{
    width: 42px;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    border-right: 1px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
    border-top-right-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}

.panel-lefttitle
{
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: 15px;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: inherit;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: left top;
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform-origin: left top;
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform-origin: left top;
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform-origin: left top;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform-origin: left top;
    position: absolute;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.panel-rightbody
{
    float: left;
    margin-left: 45px;
    padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
    <div class="page-header">
    </div>
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-6">

<div class="panel panel-primary">
  <div class="panel-leftheading">
      <h3 class="panel-lefttitle">Panel title</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-rightbody">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      
  </div>
    <div class="clearfix">
    </div>
</div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the `width` and the `margin` of your `h3`, deleted the `transform` and changed `white-space`.

If you want to change the alignment of letters, you can change the `text-align`.

Here is the solution for your need:

```css
.panel {
  position: relative;
}
.panel-default > .panel-leftheading {
  color: #333;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border-color: #ddd;
}
.panel-primary > .panel-leftheading {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #428bca;
  border-color: #428bca;
}
.panel-success > .panel-leftheading {
  color: #3c763d;
  background-color: #dff0d8;
  border-color: #d6e9c6;
}
.panel-info > .panel-leftheading {
  color: #31708f;
  background-color: #d9edf7;
  border-color: #bce8f1;
}
.panel-warning > .panel-leftheading {
  color: #8a6d3b;
  background-color: #fcf8e3;
  border-color: #faebcc;
}
.panel-danger > .panel-leftheading {
  color: #a94442;
  background-color: #f2dede;
  border-color: #ebccd1;
}
.panel-leftheading {
  width: 42px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border-right: 1px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
.panel-lefttitle {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-left: 0px;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: inherit;
  position: absolute;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  width: 7px;
  line-height: 16px;
  text-align: left;
}
.panel-rightbody {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 45px;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="page-header">
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">

      <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-leftheading">
          <h3 class="panel-lefttitle">Panel title</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-rightbody">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
            irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
            irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

        </div>
        <div class="clearfix">
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```