# Split word into letter and get data of each letter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm hoping this makes sense to someone. It's based a little on the following: [How to rotate individual letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12631043/how-do-i-rotate-individual-letters-and-keep-them-flowing-left-to-right).

```
$(".target").html(("<span>"+$(".target").html().split("").join("</span><span>")+"</span>"));
```

What I'm hoping to do then, is add a text-stroke-outline to a pseudo:before element for each letter.

Basically I'd like the html output to go from

```
<h1 class="rotate tk-ad">
  <span class="target">Ride</span>
</h1>
```

to:

```
<h1 class="rotate tk-ad">
<span class="target"><span data-glitch="R">R</span><span data-glitch="i">i</span><span data-glitch="d">d</span><span data-glitch="e">e</span></span>
</h1>
```

Comment: `<span data-glitch="R">R<span>` That's a typo, right? You wanted an end tag, not a start tag at the end there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a plain regular expression `replace` for this, without creating any arrays or anything like that:

```js
const target = document.querySelector('.target');
target.innerHTML = target.textContent
  .replace(/\w/g, '<span data-glitch="$&">$&</span>');
console.log(target.innerHTML);
```

```html
<span class="target">Ride</span>
```

Comment: I know it's been a little while now, wondering if you could help me work out how to wrap words in a div?

So if it was a multi-word span, it wouldn't break at each letter when the browser resizes?

'Ri an' would become
<div class="word"><span data-glitch="R">R</span><span data-glitch="i">i</span></div><div class="word"><span data-glitch="a">a</span><span data-glitch="n">n</span></div>

Comment: It's not entirely trivial, do you want to post a new question?