# Looking to split sentence into words (as div), then words into letters (as spans)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

Based on my previous question seen here: [Split word into letter and get data of each letter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51510324/split-word-into-letter-and-get-data-of-each-letter/51510364)
I'm trying to work out a way to split the sentence into words as divs beforehand.

The current code is as follows:

```
const target = document.querySelector('.target');
target.innerHTML = target.textContent
  .replace(/\w/g, '<span data-b-text="$&">$&</span>');
```

The fiddle I've attempted based on other answers I've found:
https://jsfiddle.net/xyp3cn37/7/

The result I'm trying to achieve is:

```
<h1 class="rotate tk-ad">
  <span class="target">A Word</span>
</h1>
```

to:

```
<h1 class="rotate tk-ad">
 <span class="target">
   <div>
    <span data-glitch="A">A</span>
   </div>
   <div>
    <span data-glitch="W">W</span><span data-glitch="o">o</span><span data-glitch="r">r</span><span data-glitch="d">d</span>
  </div>
 </span>
</h1>
```

I'm then rotating each individual letter (this is working, so no real need to include that code) to result in:
[image: Final Output]
However, on smaller screens, this happens due to the HTML only seeing each letter, not each word:
[image: Breaks on letter not word]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with two regular expressions - one to match the words, and then use a replacer function to replace each character in the word with a `span`. First match `\w+` (not just `\w`, that'll only match one character) to match all words, then replace each character in the word with `/./g`:

```js
const target = document.querySelector('.target');
target.innerHTML = target.textContent
  .replace(/\w+/g, (word) => (
    '<div>' +
    word.replace(/./g, '<span data-glitch="$&">$&</span>') +
    '</div>'
  ));
console.log(target.innerHTML);
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black
}
```

```html
<span class="target">A Word Here</span>
```

Comment: Thanking you! I've gone with this one as it matches what was already in place (a little less learning for me)

Answer (score 0):

While settinf the html of the `.target` you can first split the string based on spaces and then split it on each character and build the string.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".target").html(function() {
    return $(this).html().split(" ").map(word => {
      return '<div>' + word.split("").map(alphabet => {
        return '<span data-glitch="'+alphabet+'">' + alphabet + '</span>';
      }).join("") + '</div>';
    })
  })
});
```

```css
div {
  margin: 20px;
}

span {
  padding: 0 20px;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1 class="rotate tk-ad">
  <span class="target">A Word</span>
</h1>
```

Comment: Note 2nd argument of html(function) is the current html

Comment: I am not using 2nd argument in the code here. Accessing it using `this`.

Comment: just suggesting...since it's already there without needing to get it again

Comment: Thanks for this! I've gone with the other answer purely as I can somewhat understand it a little more.